# Create a numpy mask with edge detection

Tags: python, numpy, mask, nifti

I am working with a nifti image that I converted into a numpy array.
This is the code, I've done to obtain the edge of the picture:

```
import ants
img = ants.image_read("image.nii.gz")
img_numpy = img.numpy()

# For the edge detection
sx=ndimage.sobel(img_numpy,axis=0,mode='constant')
sy=ndimage.sobel(img_numpy,axis=1,mode='constant')
edge=np.hypot(sx,sy)
```

And the original image:
[image]
After detecting the edges of the picture, I want to create a mask inside of those edges.

This is the pictures with edges detection:
[image: image with edge detection]

And this is the mask I want to obtain (I draw the mask on LIFEx):
[image: image with edge detection and the mask i want]

I've seen a lot of this done on OpenCV but sadly I didn't found a way to use OpenCV with nifti pictures so I am using numpy instead.

Thanks

Ps: Here is link for the numpy array that I use: [img_array](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hdSo9Vzvfs7ImBk3AclQqd_Xj7OMhnvj/view?usp=sharing), here is link for the original nifti image: [nifti image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Z-dfoMg67F50XixnDKWBzC3hqabcxEF/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide us what you have coded so far?

Comment: May be try https://simpleitk.org/ ? And you may use all opencv functionality with np.ndarrays

Comment: Also, I found this channel very helpful when I was using OpenCV: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Qnb8Wv2p1c

Comment: It is very hard to tell without the original image, but basically you should use the Canny edge detector with a threshold which will provide an image with only the outline (i.e., without any white edges inside the desired area) and then just use the `cv2.bitwise_not()` to get the mask.

Comment: Thanks for your comments i added some code and the original picture. I will check with OpenCV and simpleitk

Comment: You may use openCV yes